# How to execute powershell script from server1 for deploying wsp in server2

Tags: powershell, solution-package

I am trying to run a powershell script in server1 to deploy WSP file present in server2. Here is my code:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username",$password)
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell –EA 0
Update-SPSolution -Identity TechSoup.Web.wsp -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files ...Debug\Some.wsp" -GacDeployment
```

I am successfully able to enter server2 using the first 3 lines. I now want to run the bottom two lines as administrator on server2 from server1. I am getting this error:

> Update-SPSolution : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the
>   local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that  you
>   have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying
>   again.

Can anyone help me with this ?? I need to deploy the wsp solution remotely.

Comment: If someone can suggest a solution with executing remote script(remotely running the powershell script for deployment), that will also suffice.

Comment: I believe the error is coming because I don't have admin privileges, because when I run the deployment code from server2 as admin, the wsp file is getting deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer here:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497393/how-to-execute-powershell-script-from-server1-for-deploying-wsp-in-server2)

I hope this helps someone who needs this.

Here is how it worked  for me:

On Client:

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Enable-WSmanCredSSP -Role "Client" -DelegateComputer clientmachinename -Force
```

Also, go to gpedit.msc  and look at the following policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials and Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM.
Enable the state and add SPN to Server List for Remote Server. In our case it will be: WSMAN/clientmachinename. Click Okay, save and exit.

On Server: (Where WSP file is present and needs to be deployed)

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Enable-WSmanCredSSP -Role Server
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxShellsPerUser="25"}'
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="600"}'
```

Click Yes/Yes to all till the dialog box appear.

Now Our System is configured for Remote execution of Powershell command.

Once, this is done, go to Client and run this command:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "your password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username",$password)
Invoke-command -computername yourServerName -credential $cred -authentication CredSSP -scriptblock {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell –EA 0 
Update-SPSolution -Identity yourfile.wsp -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\(location of your file)...\yourfile.wsp" -GacDeployment}
```

The above script will deploy our wsp file to Server. Make sure that you run these commands in administrator mode.